# Использовать CID в ссылке на фотографию в электронной почте

Tags: html, email, вёрстка-email

При формировании электронного письма генерируем CID и загружаем в приложения файл. Картинки отображаются корректно

```
<img src = "cid:cidgenreate">
```

Необходимо сделать фотографии кликабельными, пробовал делать так:

```
<a href = "CID:cidgenreate">тут что то есть</a>
```

gmail генерирует ссылку которая ведет на страницу 404, яндекс отказывается обрабатывать такие ссылки.
Как сделать ссылку на файл/картинку используя CID?